# jQueryUI autocomplete - encoding problem

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have problem with encoding in jQueryUI Autocomplete.
Server side application is PHP and send reply for this query with headers:

```
Content-Type: application/json, charset=UTF-8
```

Here is autocomplete code:

```
$('#city').autocomplete({
    source: 'ajax_get_cities.html',
    dataType: "json",
    minLength:3
});
```

When I type: kra (expected result is: Kraków) I get reply (copied from Firebug raw reply):

```
[{"city":"Krak\u00f3w"}]
```

and autocomplete doesn't display this result.
Database table, field, connection, PHP file, all is UTF-8.
Where is problem?

**Update**
This is server side problem, PHP application based on KohanaPHP 2.3.4 framework.
Here is code to get and display result:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json, charset=UTF-8');
$mModel = new Partners_Model();
$str = $this->input->get('term', true);
$aCities = $mModel->getCitiesAjax($str);
echo json_encode($aCities);
```

When I disply $aCities array then I get correct string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The local data can be a simple Array of Strings, or it contains
>   Objects for each item in the array, with either a label or value
>   property or both.

add label property to your json response:

```
[{"label":"Krak\u00f3w"}]
```

DOCS: [Autocomplete Widget | jQuery UI API Documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source) - option "source"

Comment: In current version, there is also an option to use function as data source :) (downside is that you have to do the search "yourself")

Answer (score 0):

add this to your `autocomplete`:

```
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
```

Comment: doesn't work, this is server side problem. When I try get this address direct in browser I get same result.